# Oracle SQL where clause against a timestamp column

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am executing the below SQL query but the query does not return any row even though the entries corresponding to selected date are present in the table.

```
    Date getdatetemp =  datechooser.getDate();     // getting the date selected by user
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    java.sql.Date extdate=new java.sql.Date(getdatetemp.getTime());
    String getdate=sdf.format(extdate);
    String sql="SELECT * from registration_timestamp where timestamp_registered=TO_DATE('"+getdate+"','dd/MM/yyyy')";
    PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet res=pst.executeQuery();  
    pst.close();
    res.close();
```

Comment: better show us; the code for insertion in DB  also.

Comment: select to_char(timestamp_registered, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') from registration_timestamp;  Check in DB what date stored?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar the query returned **2013/02/03 11:03:16**

Comment: So you have time along with date; but searching with only date (sql.date not util.date) :(. Please ensure datechooser.getDate() is returning the same time along with Date; then just pass getdatetemp like Nizet told (stmt.setDate(1, extDate);)

Comment: I agree with Nizet if you want to search only by Date without time then  use "trunc(timestamp_registered)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Learn about prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), and use native types instead of strings:

```
java.sql.Date extDate = new java.sql.Date(getDateTemp.getTime());
String sql = "SELECT * from registration_timestamp where timestamp_registered=?";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setDate(1, extDate);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

That said, since you're talking about timestamps, and timestamps have a precision that goes to the nanosecond, the problem could be that the date stored in the database has a time part in addition to a date part:

```
16/02/2013 != 16/02/2013 18:54:32 123421
```

If that's the case (and it seems it is), compare the chosen date with the timestamp truncated to a date:

```
select * from registration_timestamp where trunc(timestamp_registered) = ?
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm#i79761

Comment: hmm i agree that 16/02/2013 != 16/02/2013 18:54:32 123421 so what shall i do i want to just search by date i am not interested in the time part

Comment: `select * from registration_timestamp where trunc(timestamp_registered) = ?`. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm#i79761

Comment: trunc() might work but using functions in the where clause slow down performance.  This is especially true if the field you are truncating is indexed.

Comment: @DanBracuk: nothing prevents you from indexing `trunc(timestamp_registered)`.

Comment: In my situation, there often is something preventing me from indexing anything - lack of permission.  However, that's my situation, not anybody else's.

Answer (score 0):

When your columns are datetime and you want to search on a date range, you do this:

```
select whatever
from yourtables
where yourdatefield >= DateA
and yourdatefield < the day after DateB
```

Combine this logic with the answer from @JBNizet and Bob's your uncle.